# Possible to create a funnel using flurry event parameters?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I have a few events in my apps that have parameters For example

Ads - Custom Event
Network Name - event param 
Status - event param

So the main event is Ads and I'm passing in the network name say "Admob" for example and the status so "Failed" for example.

Is it possible in flurry to see how many users who saw the "Admob" network also returned a status of "Failed"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there a couple of ways that you can calculate the number of user who triggered an event with a specific parameter value.

1) From https://dev.flurry.com open your project and visit Manage -> Segments. You can create a segment of users that have triggered an event with a specific parameter value.

2) You can use Flurry's Explorer tool to perform the calculation very quickly. See the green banner at the top of the developer portal or the 'Explorer' link from the project page.